# How the UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource methods get automatically called?

Tags: ios

Just conforming to the datasource and delegate protocol and assigning the delegate and data source object in my class implementation file and defining the methods defined under the datasource and delegate protocol is all anyone need?How does those methods get called automatically?

Comment: When UITableView is rendered on screen or any actions are made, it will call certain methods in its own datasource and/or delegate.

Comment: Once you have your delegate and datasource assigned call `reloadData` on your `tableview`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a kind of design pattern, which expose to you as many methods as needed to give you enough flexibility to control it and hide from you all the hard work.

Since you're assigning self to delegate and datasource properties, that mechanism is just calling those exposed protocol method on object which is the "self". Those methods are called while it's building up dynamic content, while reloading, etc.

If you're interested with implementation, you could check this open class with the same design pattern:

[iCarousel](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel)